# SQL sort by year-month from timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, timestamp

I have a table with two timestamps (created_at, confirmed_at)

I want to sort my result by the year and month of created_at and within the month by confirmed at:

Data:

```
created_at, confirmed_at
2018-12-23, 2018-12-06
2018-12-15, 2019-01-20
2019-01-08, 2019-01-11
2019-01-12, 2019-01-13
```

Result:

```
created_at, confirmed_at
2019-01, 2019-01-13
2019-01, 2019-01-11
2018-12, 2019-01-20
2018-12, 2018-12-06
```

How can I use a timestamp to sort by YYYY-mm (and how can I make it fast -> how can I index for this query?)

Answer (score 2):

With year() and month() functions:

```
select 
  year(created_at) created_year, 
  month(created_at) created_month, 
  confirmed_at 
from t
order by created_year, created_month, confirmed_at
```

or if you want only the YYYY-MM part:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m"), confirmed_at from t
order by year(created_at), month(created_at), confirmed_at
```

or:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m") created, confirmed_at from t
order by created, confirmed_at
```

or:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m") created, confirmed_at from t
order by EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM created_at), confirmed_at
```

Comment: this takes several seconds. Can I create an index with the year/month function?

Comment: You can't create indexes for functions, only for columns. Try my edited answer (3d query)

Comment: Try also the 4th

Comment: All 4 queries take about the same time. So my only option would be to add separate columns for year and month to get an index?

Comment: The indexes (if any) are already used, so using less functions is better. Let me edit with year and month only.

Comment: Check the  1st query.